# woocommerce login form submit with button instead on input

Tags: php, forms, woocommerce

I'm wanting to use a button element rather than input on the woocommerce login form, purely for styling reasons. So rather than

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="login" value="Login" />
```

I want to use

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Login</button>
```

This doesn't work though and I've no idea why.

Comment: Add `name="login"` to your `button` element.

Comment: I had already tried that and it didn't work and just tried again and it's not working.

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="login">Login</button>`

Comment: You can apply any CSS style to input button element also, so why you want to change the element?

Comment: inputs don't allow :before and :after

Answer (score 1):

Just found it out the button element need the value setting the same as the input i.e.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="login" value="Login">Login</button>
```